# Is it possible to bind a mouse event to a tab of a notebook?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, tabs

I'm using the notebook from `tkinter`.
And I need to close a tab when I'm doing a right click on it.
But I can't find a way to handle any event on it.
So I hope that someone can help me.
I just need an example, so if you need anything(code, etc) ask me.

[image: Demonstration by picture]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can `bind()` event `<Button-3>` (right button) to `notebook` with function which will close selected `tab`.

```
 nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
 nb.bind('<Button-3>', on_click)
```

Problem is how to recognize clicked `tab` because tkinter sends only `x`, `y`.

`Tcl/Tk` has function `indentity tab x y` to convert `x`, `y` to `tab index`. But `tkinter` doesn't have it. You have to call `Tcl` command:

```
 clicked_tab = nb.tk.call(nb._w, "identify", "tab", x, y)
```

and now you can use this index to close tab.

(you can see similar command `indentify` in `ttk.py` file)

---

Simple working example

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- functions ---

def on_click(event):
    print('widget:', event.widget)
    print('x:', event.x)
    print('y:', event.y)

    #selected = nb.identify(event.x, event.y)
    #print('selected:', selected) # it's not usefull

    clicked_tab = nb.tk.call(nb._w, "identify", "tab", event.x, event.y)
    print('clicked tab:', clicked_tab)

    active_tab = nb.index(nb.select())
    print(' active tab:', active_tab)

    if clicked_tab == active_tab:
        nb.forget(clicked_tab)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# create notebook
nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill='both')

# bind function to notebook
nb.bind('<Button-3>', on_click)    

# add some tabs
for char in "ABCDEF":
    nb.add(tk.Label(nb, text=(char*15)), text=char*3)

root.mainloop()
```

If you remove `if clicked_tab == active_tab:` then you could close every `tab`, not only active.

Comment: According to the Python and tk ttk docs, `Notebook.forget` works with any 'tab_id', not just a tab index.  If the 'name's returned by Notebook.identify()` and `Notebook.select()` are tab_ids, as they must be for `Notebook.index` to work, it would seem that the `tk.call` and `nb.index` calls are not needed.  True??

Comment: @TerryJanReedy on my computer `identify()` returns always string `label` or `padding` - but it is not tab ID or tab index :/ I found `indentify tab` in tk docs. It returns tab index so I need `nb.index()` to convert  tab ID (`nb.select()`) into tab index to compare `clicked tab` with `active tab`.

Comment: I wonder if that is intentional.  The doc, such as it is, is pretty vague.  It just occurred to me that one could subclass a widget such as Notebook and add more useful tk.call wrappers.

Comment: Oh, for any Mac users out there, '<Button-3>' would be '<Button-2>' on OS X.